# Grid.Mvc sorting not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, grid.mvc

I've created a grid using Grid.Mvc.  For some reason sorting is not working on it.  When I click on the column to sort it, it just reloads the page.  I'm very new to MVC and not sure how to fix this.  Here is my code.

```
@Html.Grid(Model.StudentCrsHist).Columns(columns => 
       {               
           columns.Add(x => x.YR_CDE)
               .Titled("YR_CDE")
               .SetWidth(110)                   
               .Sortable(true);

           columns.Add(x => x.TRM_CDE)
               .Titled("TRM_CDE")
               .SetWidth(110)                   
               .Sortable(true);

           columns.Add(x => x.SUBTERM_CDE)
               .Titled("SUBTERM_CDE")
               .SetWidth(110)                   
               .Sortable(true);

           columns.Add(x => x.CRS_CDE)
               .Titled("CRS_CDE")
               .SetWidth(110)                   
               .Sortable(true);

           columns.Add(x => x.CRS_DIV)
               .Titled("CRS_DIV")
               .SetWidth(110)                   
               .Sortable(true);

           columns.Add(x => x.CREDIT_HRS)
               .Titled("CREDIT_HRS")
               .SetWidth(110)                   
               .Sortable(true);

           columns.Add(x => x.CRS_TITLE)
               .Titled("CRS_TITLE")
               .SetWidth(110)                   
               .Sortable(true);

           columns.Add(x => x.ADD_FLAG)
               .Titled("ADD_FLAG")
               .SetWidth(110)                   
               .Sortable(true);

           columns.Add(x => x.ADD_DTE)
               .Titled("ADD_DTE")
               .SetWidth(110)                   
               .Sortable(true)
               .Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");

           columns.Add(x => x.DROP_FLAG)
               .Titled("DROP_FLAG")
               .SetWidth(110)                   
               .Sortable(true);

           columns.Add(x => x.DROP_DTE)
               .Titled("DROP_DTE")
               .SetWidth(110)
               .Sortable(true)
               .Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}");
       })
```

Comment: **[This link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)** might be helpful

Comment: I am having the same issue.  I also noticed that my rows do not hightlight when I hover over them.  Have you found a solution?

Comment: antman it sounds like you are missing the javascript files.  In my project with grid.mvc working I have included:
`<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Gridmvc.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js")" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/gridmvc.datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Answer (score 0):

You should add the Sortable capabilty to your grid.
In your code change the last line to be:

```
}).Sortable()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your Grid in the declaration, like

```
@Html.Grid((IEnumerable<project_name.Models.Host>)ViewBag.Hosts).Named("assessmentsGrid").Columns(columns =>
```

If that does not work I would check your javascript files in your _Layout page.  Are you sure you included:

- ~/Scripts/gridmvc.min.js
- ~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js
- "~/Content/Gridmvc.css"

Note: I did NOT have to put .Sortable() on my table declaration to get column sorting to work, only had to put .Sortable(true) on my column declarations.  My grid ends like `}).WithPaging(10).WithMultipleFilters()`

I hope this helps you out. Comment if it doesn't we can try something else.